# Reloading NAT configuration on a running VMWare Server 2.0.2

Tags: linux, networking, nat, vmware-server

I have a server running VMWare Server 2.0.2. The host is Debian Lenny. I have 15-20 virtual machines running, all attached to a single NAT network (named vmnet8).

I have configured VMWare's NAT (the **vmnet-natd** daemon) to forward some incoming to ports to one of the VMs, since it hosts some publicly accessible services. I did this via the file `/etc/vmware/vmnet8/nat/nat.conf` by adding lines like the following:

```
80 = 192.168.100.100:80
```

This works great, I can reach the web server on the VM at 192.168.100.100 by connecting to the host's IP address.

Sometimes, I need to add port redirections to this NAT configuration. So, I add a line to the configuration file.

Now for the question. How do I make the natd process take this new configuration into account? Clearly, restarting the host machine **does** take it into account, and the newly added port is forwarded. However, this is not an option on this server, so how should one do this **without** restarting the whole host?

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like the only way to apply VMWare NAT's new config is to kill the running vmware-natd process and restart it, but i may be wrong ([source](http://communities.vmware.com/message/103533#103533))

Comment: Well, that sure worked. Thanks for the tip, I hadn't thought of that (doh). So hackish for such "professional" software...

Comment: i agree, i'd have thought an app like vmware server would provide ways to do this cleanly, but it seems it doesn't

Answer (score 6):

I am working at workstation 10.0.4 , I use the following instructions to make nat.conf to take effect after every change,wihtout rebooting computer.

```
vmware-networks --stop
vmware-networks --start
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this works on VMware server 2.0 but in VMware Server 1.10 you can just restart the networking service like this :

/usr/lib/vmware/net-services.sh restart

Comment: Nope, I don't seem to have that script in my VMWare installation. Thanks anyway!